# Get first value if there is a match

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, match, typeerror

Ok, so I have a simple variable declaration with a match regex query.

```
var image = decl.val.match(/(url\(.*\))/)[1];
```

But I found out quickly I cannot do this because sometimes there is no match and instead of returning undefined or something like that an error comes up:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

I would like to fix this as inline as possible as I will have to iterate this many times throughout my code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: _“I would like to fix this as inline as possible as I will have to iterate this many times throughout my code.”_ – you familiar with a concept called “function” …?

Comment: @CBroe Yes I am but I would like to do this using conditional ternary operators... It is kind of just a preference.

Comment: Shortest one-liner you can probably get is `var image = decl.val.match(…); image = image ? image[1] : ""` (or whatever your preferred alternative to `""` is.)

Comment: True... this was more for my own information, but I wanted to see if there was any way of writing a conditional like var m = decl.val.match(/url(.*)/) ?: this[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to find magic 1 line solution you can do:

```
var m = decl.val.match(/url\(.*\)/);
var image = m ? m[0] : "";
```

Comment: Yeah... I figured I could do that... but I was wondering if there was some hidden ternary operator I did not know about. Like if you could do var m = decl.val.match(/url\(.*\)/) ?: this[1];

Comment: I am already using ternary operator if you notice. It is possible in one line by calling `test` and then `match` but that is still evaluating regex twice.

Comment: So there is no such thing as   var m = decl.val.match(/url(.*)/) ?: this[1];

Comment: No `this` has totally different meaning.

Comment: But there is no way to replicate that functionality?

Comment: As I answered yes there is inefficient way of calling test and then match but this is probably cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest one-liner you can probably get is
`var image = decl.val.match(/(url\(.*\))/)); image = image ? image[1] : ""`
(Or whatever your preferred alternative to `""` is.)

---

Oh well, come to think of it, you can still go a little further with
`var image = (image = decl.val.match(/(url\(.*\))/)) ? image[1] : "";`
if that looks better to you …

This works due to the fact that variables are “hoisted” in JavaScript – that means first the code is searched for all variable declarations (`var image` in this case) and those variables are created, and the actual code is executed only after that.